# Django NoReverseMatch exception with cache_page in urls.py

Tags: python, django

## Question

Why does using the `cache_page` function in `urls.py` under Django 1.4 cause a NoReverseMatch error when using the `url` tag in a template?

### Setup

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    '''Display the home page'''
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

#### urls.py

Following the `cache_page` [directions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from my_project.my_app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', cache_page(60 * 60)(views.index)),
)
```

#### index.html

```
{% url my_project.my_app.views.index %}
```

#### Error Message

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'my_project.my_app.views.index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The offending line the error message points out is, of course:

```
{% url my_project.my_app.views.index %}
```

### What I've tried so far

- A ton of googling and searching on SO
- Simplifying code down to the example above to rule out other conflicts
- Used `cache_page` in `views.py` as a decorator successfully (not recommended according to docs)
- Offerings to our all-powerful Django overlords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing reverse, Django tries to match by

- `URL` label
- dotted path
- callable

In your code, `'my_project.my_app.views.index'` is dotted path, then Django would get the actual function `index()` and use it as the key to match the reversed URL, by looking up in the mapping dictionary `django.core.urlresolvers.get_resolver(None).reverse_dict`.

However, when you wrap the `view.index` by `cache_view`, the key in the mapping dictionay becomes the wrapper. Thus the lookup fails and `NoReverseMatch` is raised. This is inconvenient and error-prone, but I'm not sure whether it is a bug.

You could then solve this by either use `URL` label

```
url(r'^$', cache_page(60 * 60)(views.index), name='my_index'),
{# in template #}
{% url my_index %}
```

or used `cache_page` in `views.py` as a decorator as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to solve, as you recommended, by adding `name='my_index` to my line in urls.py and `{% url my_index %}` to the template.

Comment: Also, as you point out, I'm not sure if it's a bug either, but it's at least a shortcoming of the documentation to recommend the `urls.py` cache_page usage and not mention changing template url tags.